# How to use sqlserver to store session state?

Tags: asp.net

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer"
  cookieless="true"
  regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
  timeout="30"
  sqlConnectionString="Data Source=MICHAEL;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  stateNetworkTimeout="30"/>
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How do you know you have done anything wrong?  There is no stated problem in the question.

Comment: I get the following error.


Failed to login to session state SQL server for user 'Chandan-PC\Chandan'.

Comment: Ensure SQL Server is allowing SQL Server authentication. In SSMS, Server Properties > Security > Server authentication > SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you run the [aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) tool to setup sql server?

an example command would be

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -S MICHAEL -E -ssadd -sstype t`

Comment: No. Do I have to run that? where can I get it from?

Comment: it is in the windows directory under C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<versionNumber>\aspnet_regsql.exe. i added sample command to my answer, but you can run aspnet_regsql /? to get all the options

Comment: Ok. I ran the exe and I have the required tables created but I still get an error.


Failed to login to session state SQL server for user 'Chandan-PC\Chandan'.

Comment: running the command or in asp.net? you might have to specify the username and password in the command if you aren't added as a user on the db via your windows credentials

Comment: The exe that you have told me to run has created app services, such as, membership,roles...but doesnt have any table for session

Comment: did you run through the gui or the command line i have in the answer? the tool does _all_ of those things, but the -ssadd tells it to add session stuff

Comment: I went to windows directory and ran the exe.

Comment: run it from the command prompt with the parameters i have in my answer.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -S MICHAEL -E -ssadd -sstype t

Comment: Nope. The command doesnt work in v2.0 it says login failed for user chandan. Unable to connect to sql server

Comment: login failed on aspnet_regsql or in asp.net? if aspnet_regsql then add the -U <username> and -P <password> parameters to the command. if in asp.net, then your problem is with the Integrated Security=SSPI in the web.config, in which you'll have to put the username and password in query string (or setup your server to do SSPI)

Comment: Ok Buddy. I managed to install it as per your details. Do I need to change anything in web.config

Comment: Jesus Christ!! It worked. Thanks Darren...THANKS A MILLION!!! I feel like giving you an award or something....KUDOS to YOU!!!

Comment: Hey Darren!!! I was just wondering why the timeout parameter is not timing out the session? I have set it to 1. Session doesnt time out at all

Comment: how are you checking that it didn't timeout? waiting 2 minutes and seeing if session variable still there? i don't know why it wouldn't timeout, but i do know that the data wouldn't be deleted right when it times out (sql server agent task comes through periodically and cleans them out), but the cookie should timeout (thus starting a new session)

Answer (score 0):

@Darren nailed it but here's the complete answer if someone runs into persistent vs tempdb issue.

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -S SERVERNAME -E -ssadd -sstype p` is for persistent option

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -S SERVERNAME -E -ssadd -sstype t` is for tempdb option